# Could not figure out why I got a question ban, is it unfair?

Tags: support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Recently, I noticed that I could not ask questions anymore because my current IP address have been banned. I am very confused, especially when I read that it is caused by bad questions or answers. I reviewed every questions that I ask (only 2 so far), and every answers I wrote (approximately 50 according to my SO history, which have in average 0, 1 or 2 upvotes and nothing stated as "really bad").

The FAQ says that I must improve the questions that are poorly asked, downvoted, etc. It won't do it in my situation because I reviewed them all and found nothing that could justify my question ban.

As mentioned above, I answered more questions than I asked and actually helped people with my answers. Am I wrong if I say that I am not the best candidate for a question ban ??

Any help is greatly appreciated !
Thank you

---

**UPDATE:**

I finally got unbanned. What did it is answering many questions with positive scores until I "leveled-up".

In my opinion, the auto-ban should had noticed me that I was at the edge of being banned. For a beginner, it is unclear that the "delete" button is really heavy on the ban counter. After then, the pattern was to post a question in Meta because you more likely don't know why you got banned. Reputed users then explain that you have deleted questions that should be put back and improved. The problem is, a new user has limited management permissions including its inability to undelete / see his deleted questions.

At the end, it looks like a dead lock. I honestly didn't care too much about not being able to ask questions since I prefer to answer them. Still, I think this was unclear what I could do to get unbanned. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Were any questions or answers deleted? You mention an IP address; have you tried connecting at a different location, with a different IP address?

Comment: Could it be that you have a dynamic IP, and someone else got it banned on SO previously? I know that should be hell of a coincidence, but can't think of anything else...

Comment: Do you share an IP with others? If you really have no deleted downvoted questions or answers, the ban could not have been caused by your contributions.

Comment: Good chance you are browsing from your work place (or using VPN to the work place from home hence same IP) and one of the other employees there got the ban, affecting everyone.

Comment: I do not share my IP with others, but I think that I deleted 1 or 2 answers that were not really answering correctly, and I assumed that by deleting them. It didn't happend more than 1 or 2 times, can it be enough ?

Comment: @Fred, I highly doubt that 2 bad answers out of 50 would make a difference

Comment: And would deleted *answers* really contribute to a *question* ban in any case?

Comment: I do not think I ever deleted a question, only answers (1 or 2 if my memory is correct). Otherwise, is there a way to ensure that I am right on this ?

Comment: I think deleted _questions_ (rightfully) count towards a question ban. But that looks to be unapplicable here :)

Comment: The autoban isn't glitchy. You said you had no deleted questions. You in fact had several deleted questions with low scores, which pushed you over the ban heuristic.

Comment: @Asad At this time, I had no way to know that I had deleted questions so I said what I remembered. I do a lot of stuff in a year you know :-) IMO the autoban should *at least* warn you that you are near from being banned and let you know why so you can care about it. One can honestly think that it can be useful to delete off-topic  / already-answered / finally I don't need to / not relevant or mistyped questions of his own. The SO mechanics comes later, once a user got used with the community.

Comment: I now understand that the normal user cannot delete his own questions, which is quite hard to anticipate the first time you see the "delete" option. For someone that doesn't ask many questions, this is incredibly heavy on the ban counter, yet, unclear that it is.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. A normal user *can* delete their own questions. Just not all the time.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Is it depending on how many questions have been posted yet VS. how many are deleted ? I still have only 2 active questions on SO so far so I guess it would be really bad to hit this button again if I ask questions, right?

Comment: It has to do mostly with if the question has answers that are up-voted, or if the question has been put on hold. Either of those things can prevent you from deleting it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll be more careful with that now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at your question history, you've deleted a lot of your own questions (4 out of 6).  The questions you deleted were off topic for Stack Overflow, but on topic for other communities.  In one case, if you had let the community migrate it to Super User, you would have likely not had to delete it.

Deleted questions count towards the question ban.

It looks like other questions you posed also were downvoted. That means that they need fixing.

In order to get out of your question ban, you need to do (at least) two things:

- Undelete your questions ([Which you can't do, leading to my feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146781/how-can-a-question-banned-user-fix-their-questions-if-theyre-deleted))
- Fix your questions so they get upvotes, or so they become relevant to Stack Overflow

Some future advice:

Don't ask general computing questions on Stack Overflow. It's not for problems you have with your PC, it's for programming problems.

I've edited and migrated two of the questions that look like they would be good candidates for other sites.  For the rest, take some time and improve your questions.

I've undeleted all your questions that could possibly be salvaged or migrated. The ones that couldn't will remain deleted, sorry.

Comment: Do deletions caused by migration not count towards a ban?

Comment: @CodesInChaos The question is not deleted when migrated.

Comment: I believe migrated questions get automatically deleted after a few weeks.

Comment: well, I have no intention to lie to anyone, can you please explain me how to undelete questions that I could have posted ? recently, I was seeing only 2 questions, right now (after your message) I can count 4 (2 being migrated questions); it is not a bad intention from my end

Comment: *[Y]ou need to do (at least) two things: Undelete your questions* As far as I know, users with less than 10k rep cannot undelete (or see, for that matter) deleted questions, even if they are their own. (CC @Fred)

Comment: if I am right, I am actually banned because I migrated questions to the right place when someone asked me to do it, then, to get unbanned I must undelete migrated questions, which I cannot do because I have not enough reputation point ? I sincerly do not understand

Comment: If I understand correctly, @Fred, you haven't _migrated_ the questions, but deleted them and posted afresh on the target site. Migration has to be done by either enough community members voting to migrate a question, or a moderator, you can't do that by yourself. If you learn a question is more appropriate for XY.SE, flag for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated. So it seems you're banned for misunderstanding the site's workings and terminology. Should be fixable.

Comment: actually, I am seeing this : http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg6/scaled.php?server=6&filename=profilexjr.png&res=landing (screen capture of my history), and the 2 first questions were off-topic then are now stated as "migrated", the first link leads to super user, then the second leads to web apps, I will take great care, thought, to follow these procedures when migrating

Comment: @Fred I've submitted a new feature request based on the image: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146781/. I wasn't aware you couldn't see your own deleted questions when you were banned.

Comment: @Fred you were banned for poor questions. The number of deleted questions you have figures into that banning.  Migrated questions don't count (as far as i know). You don't have the power to migrate anything. That decision is made by the community or by moderators.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker ok thank you, I will follow this up, and hope that other users in my situation do not fall in the same dead lock in the future

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I've read that it would be better to keep raising up my reputation by answering questions instead of twisting old deleted questions, is it the right approach ? I also noticed that my old deleted question that are still visible over stack,math,meta,superuser, etc has no negative scores anymore; but still can't ask questions here. Am I better to create a new account via a proxy if I want to ask questions or is it still some hope to get out of this ?? thank you

Comment: If you try to create a new account to get around a question ban, you will likely be found out and then banned, and not just question banned. Answering questions and getting reputation will help, but you should also concentrate on improving your existing questions.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I got unbanned as soon as my reputation level lifted enough to grant new permissions. Thanks. I will however stay away from the delete button :-)

Answer (score 3):

I got banned not so long ago, when doing some research into it, I found that sometimes it is a technical glitch with your IP address. Just email the support team and they can sometimes give you more information.

Unfortunately, you have to wait it out and improve all of your existing questions/answers.

Comment: Thanks! I will email them and post back here when I know what is wrong

Comment: `...you have to wait it out...` A question ban does not wear off with time.

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby guess he means wait for the team to respond, not for the ban to wear off.

Comment: @fasheikh In this case, I seriously doubt it's a technical glitch.

Comment: i was suggesting other possibilities other than bad standards, may not necessarily be the case here.