# How can a question banned user fix their questions if they're deleted?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, post-ban, vote-to-delete

If a user is question banned  and the [cause of the ban is too many deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146757/could-not-figure-out-why-i-got-a-question-ban-is-it-unfair), how can the user fix this on their own?  Until recently, advice has been to improve their questions, but since they can't see the questions on their question screen, they can't improve them:

[image]

Feature request: Allow a question banned user to see their own deleted questions, or warn them that deleting questions could lead to a question ban.

Comment: Until such thing is in place, we can advise them to post new answers, this also should lift the ban once the answers get enough upvotes.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Does that resolve a question ban?

Comment: Related: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645), [Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32675), [Warn users who are about to hit the “we are no longer accepting…” wall](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103127)

Comment: @Dennis Indeed; in this case I'm willing to keep it scoped to *just* question banned users, although in reality I'd like it to be extended to everyone.  In this case, the current logic presents a bad user experience: "You're banned, but because you deleted your posts (not knowing any better), you can't improve them, and thus can't get unbanned!* " *caveats apply.

Comment: @George I'm 99% sure of that, remember I advised it to somebody and he came back later saying it indeed lifted the ban. Let me find it..

Comment: I'd be happier if all of us could see their deleted questions, but it's more important for qbanned users. Both requests have my vote.

Comment: For what it's worth, I thought @ShaWizDowArd's suggestion _was_ the standard advice. I don't think I've seen anyone -- other than banned users themselves -- say that the solution to question bans is improving deleted questions.

Comment: He had to bring down the entire network to do it, but Kevin persevered until this change was completed.

Answer (score 41):

Why not allow any user to see their own deleted questions, even if they aren't question banned (yet)? A user might have deleted a couple of questions and, potentially, learn that they can proactively improve those to avoid a ban, instead of waiting for the ban to happen and learning how to reverse it later. I realize most won't go out of their way to learn that, but...

I think we should also consider putting more barriers in place to make it clear to users that deleting questions is not a good thing; improving them is better. I think users get delete-happy as soon as they get one or two down-votes, especially since at low rep that's such a huge impact on their rep. Under some rep threshold we should add a pop-up to say something like:

> Are you really, really sure you want to delete this question? Deleting questions can be worse for your experience here than down-votes.

Not exact wording, and probably even more elaborate, but it may make a few users think twice. As far as I can tell, it doesn't harm anything to add this kind of prompt for low-rep users except the work involved in setting it up.

And as I have expressed in the past, I think we as peers need to be better about commenting / VtC instead of down-voting poor questions. I suspect that the reactions that lead to question bans are almost always triggered by down-votes.

Comment: To appease the naysayers, you should add that this message will only appear the first time you try to delete something.  A 10K user will get quickly annoyed by this. Other than that, I like the idea. +1

Comment: @jmort253 that's why I said, specifically, `under some rep threshold`

Answer (score 23):

[Users can now see *recent* deleted questions in their profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile). We're normally not particularly eager to direct folks in that direction though, since in many cases they'd be hard-put to salvage them: most folks who hit the quality bans have made a lot more mistakes than just *deleting* their questions, if they had anything to do with the deletions at all...

Warning them first is a reasonable idea though. In fact, warning folks who try to delete their own *answered* questions would be a good idea even if the q-ban didn't exist - in many cases, this is just plain *rude!* So as of right now, anyone trying to delete their own question will see this:

[image: We do not recommend deleting questions with answers]

Folks who are *already* banned from asking questions who try to delete their own questions will see a somewhat more candid warning:

[image: Note: Deleting this question will not help you regain posting privileges.]

Deleting *unanswered* questions can actually be a good idea (it won't help you get *out* of a q-ban, but if you're prompt about cleaning up after yourself it can save you from getting in deeper), so we won't be warning about *that*. Never the less, for those who are banned, editing to improve existing questions will remain a more effective means of getting out - so those who opt for deletion instead are just digging their own grave.

It pays to read that help center article linked to from all these warnings...

Comment: So the restriction that OP can't delete his own question when it got upvoted answer or more than one answer is removed now?

Comment: Oh, hell no. But you won't find out about that restriction until you've clicked through *this* message. So *hopefully* this will not only reduce the number of users deleting their questions the second someone posts an answer, but also the number of moderator flags begging for such deletions.

Comment: Oh, that's very smart then. Kudos!

Comment: As for *"you won't find out about that restriction until you've clicked through this message*", related: [If we can't delete a question, don't show us a warning about deleting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232350/if-we-cant-delete-a-question-dont-show-us-a-warning-about-deleting-it).

Comment: there is a [complaint over at MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281464/839601) that warning is shown rather indiscriminately: asker is a high-rep old-timer, question and answer were laying dormant for over 2 years without votes...