# Duplicate of a self-deleted question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, privacy, revision-redaction

I asked a question and then saw that in the logs posted, there was some identifying information for me or my employer/client etc. Since I did not want it to remain visible in the edit history, I immediately deleted the question myself. I then cleaned up the log by masking the information, and tried to submit the question. Now it just says that this is the duplicate of another question (i.e., my deleted question). How can I submit this question?

Comment: Maybe just change the title a little?

Comment: @LanceRoberts, just tried it but it seems the duplicate detector is smart.

Comment: @LanceRoberts, thanks! Changing some of the language worked.

Answer (score 4):

In the future, if you have content that you don't really want in a question, flag it for moderator attention. We can remove the identifying information by redacting the revision history (if you tell us which revision it's in).  The problem with your approach is that the information is still out there, visible to 10K users and moderators.

Comment: Good point! It seems I can't really flag a deleted question. Deleted questions should be visible to the question owners too.

Comment: @highBandWidth [You're telling me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146781/how-can-a-question-banned-user-fix-their-questions-if-theyre-deleted).