# Deleting answered question: confirmation does not work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-delete, confirmation

I want to delete an answered question. When I click "delete", a confirmation prompt pops up discouraging me to do so, but it seems it would still allow me to continue and effectively delete the question still.

However, when I accept, I get an error that the question cannot be deleted because it has answers, and I should flag it for moderator attention.

I cannot recall the confirmation dialog coming up in the past, so I think it's new. In that case, it seems that it doesn't  work as intended yet.

The question in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492447/xpath-fails-when-using-namespaces-but-works-without-namespaces

Comment: You can delete a question with answers so long as any answer has no or negative score. As soon as any answer has a positive score, the question cannot be deleted. Could an answer have been upvoted between the time you got the prompt and trying to delete it? (btw - a link to the question would help)

Comment: That is, if any answer had a positive score when you tried to delete it, that prompt shouldn't have come up. Is that the case?

Comment: @Oded I added the link. Even when I reload the page, the prompt still comes up (so no upvoting happens in the meantime)

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I'm asking around, so those involved could get back to you.

Comment: @Oded so what's the deal with this? It got [tag:status-bydesign] but that's not right I think.

Comment: Looks like the wording was intentional (hence, by design), but we **are** discussing it internally - there are a few of us that agree that the message is not without faults ;)

Comment: @Oded Good to know, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You can only delete a question if it has no answers with a positive score. If any answer has more upvotes than downvotes or if you have accepted an answer then you can't delete the question.

The popup appears to [*discourage*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230660/248072) you from doing so even if you can as someone else in the future might find the question and answer useful.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm getting the popup even though there are upvotes and I have accepted. And just to be clear: I've reloaded the page in the meantime as well.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester - ah. That wasn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 2):

Not wild about encouraging folks to delete their answered questions, or try to delete them, or even flag for deletion. There has traditionally been [a lot of complaining and confusion surrounding this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253374/question-with-answer-deleted). To be clear, I have no problem removing questions like yours that are clearly never going to help anyone else... But we also get a lot of flags from folks who have less admirable reasons for requesting the removal.

The original discussions for [this warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146781/how-can-a-question-banned-user-fix-their-questions-if-theyre-deleted/230660#230660) assumed it would be omitted in cases where you couldn't actually delete. But while testing it, I realized I rather liked the behavior that exists now: warning folks against deleting answers *before* advising them to flag.