# Deleting own questions ban

Tags: discussion, flags, down-votes, deleted-questions

Followup of this question: [How can a question banned user fix their questions if they're deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146781/how-can-a-question-banned-user-fix-their-questions-if-theyre-deleted)

And the answer for it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230660/

Since I don't have 5 reputation, I can't ask it in a comment.

Recently a put up a question on Stackoverflow, which did not have any votes. The solution was just a typo (used the same variable name multiple times for different reasons), and it got put on-hold for not giving any useful info for future readers (and lets face it: "there is a typo in the code" is not a useful help...). However, there was a user who answered it, and since it had nothing to do with the question itself, was downvoted. Since it was useless, put on hold, I decided to delete it to save some precious bytes for more sane questions (because it was long and verbose).

But since there was one downvoted answer, Stackoverflow warned me, as deleting questions with an answer would result in a question ban.

So the question is this: is there a reason, that flagged, no vote - no non-negative, not useful, "can't be edited into a useful way" answered questions should not be freely deleted? Is it better to leave these questions lying around doing nothing?

Clarification: I did not get banned, just received the message that I will get banned for deleting posts with answers.

Comment: if you leave it lying around, it's going to be deleted anyway once enough time passes for the roomba to latch on to it. Do whichever feels best to you. Personally, i'd rather delete it sooner rather than later so that it *can* be deleted. If you wait, and someone upvotes the useless answer for whatever crazy reason, it'll be there forever.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for quickly deleted questions to count towards the ban, is that if they had no negative effect, askers could quickly delete all their questions as soon as an answer appears, before the community had a chance to downvote the question.

This would subvert the quality filters.

Comment: interested to know if the reason given is wrong, if people disagree with the reason, or if I just missed the point of the OP...